# Modify matrix df format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

Having a df as:

```
    14       15         16
14  10.1166  18.2331    65.0185
15  18.2331  6.664      57.5195
16  65.3499  57.851     20.9907
```

What is a different more efficient way to modify the df to look as

```
   a   b   c
0  14  14  10.1166
1  14  15  18.2331
2  14  16  65.0185
3  15  14  18.2331
4  15  15  6.664 
etc.
```

I wrote this code, but i dont like the fact that i need to use a loop for it.

```
for row in tt.index:
    row_vals = tt[tt.index==row]
    col_vals = row_vals.T
    col_vals['from_zone'] = row
    col_vals['to_zone'] = tt.index
    col_vals['travel_time'] = col_vals[row].astype('int')
    col_vals = col_vals.drop(row, axis=1)
    travel_data = pd.concat([travel_data,col_vals])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [58]: df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'a','level_1':'b',0:'c'})
Out[58]:
    a   b        c
0  14  14  10.1166
1  14  15  18.2331
2  14  16  65.0185
3  15  14  18.2331
4  15  15   6.6640
5  15  16  57.5195
6  16  14  65.3499
7  16  15  57.8510
8  16  16  20.9907
```

Step by step:

```
In [59]: df.stack()
Out[59]:
14  14    10.1166
    15    18.2331
    16    65.0185
15  14    18.2331
    15     6.6640
    16    57.5195
16  14    65.3499
    15    57.8510
    16    20.9907
dtype: float64

In [60]: df.stack().reset_index()
Out[60]:
   level_0 level_1        0
0       14      14  10.1166
1       14      15  18.2331
2       14      16  65.0185
3       15      14  18.2331
4       15      15   6.6640
5       15      16  57.5195
6       16      14  65.3499
7       16      15  57.8510
8       16      16  20.9907
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack` and `rename` for column names

```
In [620]: df.stack().reset_index(name='c').rename(columns={'level_0': 'a', 'level_1': 'b'})
Out[620]:
    a   b        c
0  14  14  10.1166
1  14  15  18.2331
2  14  16  65.0185
3  15  14  18.2331
4  15  15   6.6640
5  15  16  57.5195
6  16  14  65.3499
7  16  15  57.8510
8  16  16  20.9907
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `rename_axis`, `reset_index`, and [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt):

```
df.rename_axis('a').reset_index().melt(id_vars='a',var_name='b',value_name='c')
```

Output:

```
    a   b        c
0  14  14  10.1166
1  15  14  18.2331
2  16  14  65.3499
3  14  15  18.2331
4  15  15   6.6640
5  16  15  57.8510
6  14  16  65.0185
7  15  16  57.5195
8  16  16  20.9907
```